# Remove deadair periods in video

Tags: video-recording, filter

I am doing a video recording for a powerpoint presentation, and sometimes I have some seconds of (idleness) during the recording (where there is no change in the presentation nor speaking audio). For user experience reasons, I prefer to remove all such parts that are longer than 1 second (to keep the video engaging).

I am currently doing this in a manual way, but it is an extremely time-consuming process.

I was thinking if there is a way to automatically (using a tool or a filter or so) remove such parts in the video.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awkward pause script as sample and this tutorial:

Or I can do for you this project for some money :)

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution I have created: Timebolt.

Narrate your video over PowerPoint. Then add file to TimeBolt desktop app to instantly cut dead-air, rapidly remove any scene or word, speed up silences, and then render or export XML into Premiere, FCPX, and Resolve.

Takes 10 minutes to cut dead-air and fine-tune a 60 minute recording, not five hours.

[Remove silence with TimeBolt.io](https://www.timebolt.io)

[image: TimeBolt Product]